# Exception twisted._threads._ithreads.AlreadyQuit: AlreadyQuit()

Tags: scrapy, twisted

I'm running scrapy and inserting the result into mysql database. The spider doesn't finish successfully and gives me this error:

Exception twisted._threads._ithreads.AlreadyQuit: AlreadyQuit()

I'm not sure why workers die/quit.

Edit: 
Basically I used [this code](http://snipplr.com/view/82246/scraped-item-to-mysql-in-scrapy/) to insert into a table that has one field with unique index on it. 
Here's the whole error that I got:

mysql_exceptions.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry 'www.example.com' for key 'idx_url'")
2016-02-01 03:22:07 [twisted] CRITICAL:
Exception twisted._threads._ithreads.AlreadyQuit: AlreadyQuit() in > ignored

but I got this error after running for a while (sometimes close to the end)

Comment: Not sure if this would help http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-15.5.0/twisted/_threads/_convenience.py#L14

Comment: You ran some code (what code?) and got an error (beyond the exception type: what error?).  This might be a bug in your code, or in scrapy, or in Twisted, but without more inforamtion we have no way of knowing.

Comment: @Glyph You think this happens when the spider is almost done and wants to close the database?